# Automatically updating the view as a list item is added/deleted/edited in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, binding

I am making a to-do application in Angular. Right now I have the add/delete/edit functionality working but I have to refresh the web page every time to see the changes occur.

I want it so that once a to-do list item is added, the user can see the item added to the list automatically without having to refresh the page every time. Same goes for deleting and editing the items.

This is my HTML below:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" value={{toDoItem}} [(ngModel)]="toDoItem">
  <button (click)="addToDo()">Add to List</button>
</div>

<div class="items" *ngFor="let todo of todoList">
  <div >
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="todo.completed" (change)="updateCompleted(todo.id)">

    <div *ngIf="!todo.editing; else editingTodo">{{ todo.content }}</div>

    <ng-template #editingTodo>
      <input #editVal type="text" value={{updatedItem}} [(ngModel)]="todo.content" >
      <button (click)="onEdit(todo.id, editVal.value)">Save</button>
      <button (click)="toggleEdit(todo.id)">Cancel</button>
    </ng-template>

  </div>

  <div class="remove-item">
    <button (click)="removeTodo(todo.id)">Remove</button>
    <button (click)="toggleEdit(todo.id)">Edit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my typescript file with the logic below:

```
export class ToDoListComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input()
  todo: Todo;

  toDoItem: string;
  updatedItem: string;
  todoList: Todo[];
  show = false;

  constructor(private todoService: ToDoService) {
    this.toDoItem = '';
    this.updatedItem = '';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.todoList = this.todoService.getTodos();
  }

  addToDo() {
    this.todoService.addTodo(this.toDoItem);
    this.toDoItem = '';
  }

  removeTodo(id: number) {
    this.todoService.removeTodo(id);
  }

  updateCompleted(id: number) {
    this.todoService.updateComplete(id);
  }

  toggleEdit(id: number) {
    this.todoService.toggleEdit(id);
  }

  onEdit(id: number, newContent: string) {
    this.todoService.editTodo(id, newContent);
    this.todoService.toggleEdit(id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic mistake is component is not maintaining the state instead todoService is.

So Mistake : inside ToDoListComponent todoList have been initialized only once, at ngOnInit lifecycle hook.

Solution : in addToDo method after pushing value to todoService, call below line again,

```
this.todoList = this.todoService.getTodos();
```

Same should be done for update and delete to see the changes reflected for those operations.